# Top 3 Values Per Row in R

Tags: r, dataframe

My dataframe set up is:

`ID Var1 Var2 Var3 ... Var50`

The sum of the variables are 1 for every row. I've been trying to get the top 3 Variables.

`ID 1st 2nd 3rd`

Would grouping by ID and using the top_n() work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is by row,  then we can use `apply`

```
t(apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) head(sort(-x), 3)))
```

---

Or with `pmap` returning a `list` column with 3 values per row

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(top3 = select(., -ID) %>% pmap(~ head(sort(-c(...)), 3)))
```

---

If we want to use `top_n`, one option is to reshape to 'long' format

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    top_n(3, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table` you can reshape your data to long format and select the three maximum values by group ("ID")

```r
library(data.table)
df_long <- melt(df1, id.vars = "ID")[order(ID, desc(value))]
df_long[,.SD[1:3], by = "ID"]
```